# Why am I getting NaN or null in Java?

Tags: java, object

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroceryStore houstonStore = new GroceryStore();
        GroceryStore orlandoStore = new GroceryStore();
        GroceryStore seattleStore = new GroceryStore();

        double houstonStoreRevenue = ( houstonStore.applesSold * houstonStore.applesPrice) + (houstonStore.orangesSold * houstonStore.orangesPrice);
        double orlandoStoreRevenue = (orlandoStore.applesSold * orlandoStore.applesPrice) + (orlandoStore.orangesSold * orlandoStore.orangesPrice );
        double seattleStoreRevenue = (seattleStore.applesSold * seattleStore.applesPrice) + (seattleStore.orangesSold * seattleStore.orangesPrice);


        houstonStore.applesSold = 534;
        houstonStore.applesPrice = 0.99;
        houstonStore.orangesSold = 429;
        houstonStore.orangesPrice = 0.87;
        System.out.println("The Houston store revenue is: " + houstonStoreRevenue);

        seattleStore.applesSold = 765;
        seattleStore.applesPrice = 0.86;
        seattleStore.orangesSold = 842;
        seattleStore.orangesPrice = 0.91;
        System.out.println("The Seattle store revenue is: " + seattleStoreRevenue);

        orlandoStore.applesSold = 402;
        orlandoStore.applesPrice = 0.79;
        orlandoStore.orangesSold = 398;
        orlandoStore.orangesPrice = 0.77;
        System.out.println("The Orlando store revenue is: " + orlandoStoreRevenue);

    }
}
```

```
class class GroceryStore {
    int applesSold;
    double applesPrice;
    int orangesSold;
    double orangesPrice;
}
```

I don't quite understand why I am getting the answer below

```
*****
The Houston store revenue is: 0.0
The Seattle store revenue is: 0.0
The Orlando store revenue is: 0.0
```

Comment: What values do your `GroceryStore` objects have by default?  Because you're performing your calculations before you set any of those values.  The default values are *probably* zero.  (As an aside, your object should also expose setters and getters instead of allowing consuming code to directly access the values.  This would also allow you to write a method on the object itself to perform the calculation, so you don't have to repeat that logic and can just query the object.)

Comment: Please include all relevant code so that others can answer your question correctly. In this case, the `GroceryStore` class is missing.

Comment: I am confused, why does your title say "NaN or null" but your code does produce neither of them, it produces `0` (zero). Where is the Nan or null?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing attributes that haven't been declared yet.  Try this instead...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroceryStore houstonStore = new GroceryStore();
        GroceryStore orlandoStore = new GroceryStore();
        GroceryStore seattleStore = new GroceryStore();

        houstonStore.applesSold = 534;
        houstonStore.applesPrice = 0.99;
        houstonStore.orangesSold = 429;
        houstonStore.orangesPrice = 0.87;
        double houstonStoreRevenue = ( houstonStore.applesSold * houstonStore.applesPrice) + (houstonStore.orangesSold * houstonStore.orangesPrice);
        System.out.println("The Houston store revenue is: " + houstonStoreRevenue);

        seattleStore.applesSold = 765;
        seattleStore.applesPrice = 0.86;
        seattleStore.orangesSold = 842;
        seattleStore.orangesPrice = 0.91;
        double seattleStoreRevenue = (seattleStore.applesSold * seattleStore.applesPrice) + (seattleStore.orangesSold * seattleStore.orangesPrice);
        System.out.println("The Seattle store revenue is: " + seattleStoreRevenue);

        orlandoStore.applesSold = 402;
        orlandoStore.applesPrice = 0.79;
        orlandoStore.orangesSold = 398;
        orlandoStore.orangesPrice = 0.77;
        double orlandoStoreRevenue = (orlandoStore.applesSold * orlandoStore.applesPrice) + (orlandoStore.orangesSold * orlandoStore.orangesPrice );
        System.out.println("The Orlando store revenue is: " + orlandoStoreRevenue);
    }
}
```